# Erasing IBuffers in a Destructor

Tags: c#, destructor, uwp

I have a class that internally manages an IBuffer. The data is sensitive, so I would like to have the class ensure that the buffer is 0'd out before it is destroyed to avoid leaving the bits in memory. I have an Erase() method which is as follows:

```
public static void Erase(this IBuffer value)
{
    using (var writer = new DataWriter(value.AsStream().AsOutputStream()))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            writer.WriteByte(0);

        var storeTask = Task.Run(async () => await writer.StoreAsync());
        storeTask.Wait();
    }
}
```

First, I recognize that my use of Task.Run here to call a non-CPU-bound async method is suspect, but I haven't found a synchronous equivalent. Alternatives are welcome.

The problem I'm experiencing is that in Debug mode, and most of the time in Release mode, it runs perfectly. However, occasionally in Release mode, I bump into an exception when Finalize() is run on my object:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException' occurred in System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
>
> Additional information: Excep_InvalidComObject_NoRCW_Wrapper. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

The URL really only talks about the optimizations for exceptions in .Net Native, not this specific exception type.

I presume the cause may have something to do with the IBuffer being destroyed before my Erase method has a chance to complete.

How can I properly achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Use `IDisposable`, not a finalizer.

Comment: But doesn't that require the consumer of the class to explicitly call Dispose? That is not the behavior I want. And the documentation for IDisposable says "you should override Object.Finalize to free unmanaged resources in the event that the consumer forgets to call Dispose." where Object.Finalize is overridden in C# by implementing the destructor.

Comment: If your class deals with secrets that should not stay in memory, your callers _need_ to explicitly call `Dispose` (via `using`).  **Do not rely on the GC to destroy memory**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# finalizers are not like C++ destructors, even though the term "destructor" is sometimes used to describe them. A C# finalizer is not guaranteed to run at all. If the finalizer does run, the order in which it runs relative to other finalizers is not defined, so your finalizer can't rely on accessing objects that themselves have finalizers (e.g. a COM object wrapper).

So yes, it's entirely possible that if you rely on a finalizer and your finalizer attempts to use an object that itself might have a finalizer, you may find that when your finalizer runs, the object it's trying to use may already have been cleaned up.

It is true that if you implement `Dispose()`, one strategy is to also implement a finalizer (another is to use a `SafeHandle` subclass to wrap unmanaged resources). But that's just a backstop, and since finalizers aren't guaranteed to run, it's not a 100% reliable one. The guidance to implement a finalizer isn't because that's a 100% reliable way to clean things up, but rather because it's the closest you're going to get if you're dealing with buggy client code that forgets to call `Dispose()`.

So, yes…in C# the correct strategy here is to implement `IDisposable` and require clients that want the memory cleaned up safely to make sure that they follow the rules and call `Dispose()` when they are done with the object.

By the way, as far as your `Task.Run()` goes…

You should be using asynchronous methods asynchronously. E.g. don't implement `Erase()`, instead implement `EraseAsync()` and use `await` inside.

But if you really insist on waiting for them, there's no need to wrap the call in an anonymous `async` method that you execute with `Task.Run()`. That's major overkill. Just wait on the task object returned by `StoreAsync()`. You can do that e.g. by calling its `GetResults()` method (which should block until the result is actually available), or you can convert directly to a `Task<T>` object using the [`AsTask()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.astask.aspx), and of course then wait on that task object.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some good context. I do also have a proper `EraseAsync()`, it was mainly that I had a few methods where cascading async/await would have been disruptive. But looking back, I'm not even sure why I tried to wrap an awaited call in `Task.Run()` in the first place!